# Monodromy in presentations of one group over another

Tags: combinatorial-group-theory, gr.group-theory

Consider a finitely presented group $G$ with presentation $P$ given by $\left\langle g_1,\ldots,g_n|\, r_1,\ldots,r_m\right\rangle$, equipped with a homomorphism $\rho\colon\, G\to H$ to a finitely generated group $H$ (generators in the presentation are ordered). Perform a sequence of [Tietze transformations](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tietze_transformations) starting at $P$ and ending at presentation $P^\prime$ given by $\left\langle g^\prime_1,\ldots,g^\prime_n|\, r^\prime_1,\ldots,r^\prime_m\right\rangle$ which differs from $P$ by relabeling of generators (so $g_i\mapsto g_i^\prime$ for all $i$ is an isomorphism of presentations). 
Is it true that $\rho(g_i)=\rho(g_i^\prime)$ for all $i$ up to inner automorphism of $H$?

At first I thought this was trivial, but I'm worried that it might actually be false- if so, is there some way to measure such a failure of simple-connectedness of "presentations of $G$ over $H$".

Comment: Daniel: (i) Have you an example of such a sequence of Tietze transformation that relabel generators only?

(ii) Have you thought of using Fox derivatives or something of that form?


Comment: So, let $G$ be a free group $\langle g_1,g_2\rangle$ and consider the alternative presentation $\langle g_2,g_1\rangle$.  Now consider the obvious map $\rho:G\to \mathbb{Z}/2\times\mathbb{Z}/2$.

Comment: In view of HW's example, you have to allow all automorphisms of $H$, not just the inner ones. However, the statement is false even in this form: Take $G=F_n$. You would be asking if the action of $Out(F_n)$ on $Hom(G,H)/Aut(H)$ is trivial. This is clearly false too, say, for $G=SL(2,p)$, $p\ge 5$. (Same argument as in the case of the $SL(2,C)$-character varieties.) 

Comment: ... Oh dear. So it is false. Misha: What is the argument for $SL(2,C)$ character varieties? Does the statement have a chance of being true for fundamental groups of (cusped) hyperbolic 3-manifolds?

Comment: @Dan: Think first about Dehn twists acting on the character variety (and why mapping class group acts nontrivially on the Teichmuller space). The easiest case to consider is when $F_3=F_2* Z$, then apply $\phi\in Aut(G)$, where $\phi|F_2=id$ and $\phi|Z$ is conjugation by $g_1\in F_2$. Same works if $G=F_2$, use $(g_1,g_2)\to (g_1, g_1g_2)$.    

Comment: The question mentioned Tietze transformations, but no sequence of such was specified, but there is a problem. Tietze transformations on a presentation do not 'see' the order of the generators. The question seems to me to be still a bit confusing in its statement. The example of HW does not involve Tietze transformations, and what role they might play is very unclear. The problem may be in the definition of presentation. A presentation of a group is something like < X:R> together with a choice of isomorphism from the resulting quotient group to $G$.  $X$ here is a set not an ordered set.

Comment: Tim Porter: This is fair. The generators do need to be ordered, and the Tietze transformations should "see" that order. Misha's comment answers the question though- unfortunately the answer is "no". 

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is effectively answered by HW and by Misha in the comments. Namely, a sequence of Tietze transformations starting and ending at "the same" presentation defines an automorphism of $G$. But the action of $\mathrm{Out}(G)$ on $\mathrm{Hom}(G,H)/\mathrm{Aut}(H)$ is non-trivial in general.